# How can I cherry-pick a commit without duplicate avoiding rebase?

Tags: git

I have two branches: master, feature

```
(master) A - B - C
           |
(feature)  - D
```

All branches and commits are uploaded in GitHub.

I want to cherry-pick the commit C.
like this:

```
(master) A - B - C
           |
(feature)  - D - C'
```

However, If I make pull request and merge it, there will be duplicate commits.
I know that I can avoid duplicates by rebase feature branch, but then I should use force push.

How can I avoid rebase to solve this situation without duplicates?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid rebasing? It shouldn't matter if you rewrite the history on `feature`, that's *your* branch (rewriting the history on `master` might be more of a problem...). Also why does it matter that the same commit appears in both of the parents' histories for the merge commit?

Comment: well, if feature was already pushed and C shared with somebody else, that's a huge amount of assumptions. The safest would be to assume that C is public and somebody else has already based their work on it.

Answer (score 1):

You could make another branch "feature aux".
Then merge master into that new branch.
Then in case you need it you can merge D at any point.
Remember, branches are free